# How to add comments to requests with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I want to add a comment to every request send by active record in order to found source in mysql slow query. How can I modify the request before ActiveRecord sends it?

For example i want to have this in my central mysql slow query log.

```
SELECT * FROM articles
-- File: refresh-article.rb
```

Comment: You can look into your logs I think. Or you can use something like newrelic

Comment: In Sequel you would do `require 'logger'; DB.loggers << Logger.new(STDOUT)` to see the request and timings. Google for ActiveRecord logging, perhaps.

Comment: I edit the question in order to clarify it

Comment: Note: the OP is referring to this log, where MySQL can be configured to automatically log any queries that take longer than a configurable threshold: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem with monkey patch

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter.class_eval do
    def execute_with_log(sql, name=nil)
        sql = "-- Script: #{$0}\n#{sql}"
        execute_without_log(sql, name)
    end
    alias_method_chain :execute, :log
end
```

Answer (score 3):

ActiveRecord already logs db requests with timing information to your app log.

Comment: Perhaps show how to access this log? Is this true in production environment?

Comment: They are in log/. Seems like that one could have been left has an exercise to the user ;) Yes, it is true in production.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord 6 allows queries to be annotated

```
User.annotate("selecting user names").select(:name)
# SELECT "users"."name" FROM "users" /* selecting user names */

User.annotate("selecting", "user", "names").select(:name)
# SELECT "users"."name" FROM "users" /* selecting */ /* user */ /* names */
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-annotate

You could combine this with the `caller_locations` kernel method:

```
User.annotate("#{caller_locations(1,1).first}").select(:name)
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/2.0.0/Kernel:caller_locations

Answer (score 0):

In your rails app, you can see your queries with timing in `log/(production|development).log`.

However if you want anything more than that, I suggest checking out [NewRelic in development mode](http://support.newrelic.com/kb/docs/developer-mode). It is free, and it shows your the source of where that query was executed(which looks like what you want). It really is one of the best logging/performance analyzer out there.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by monkey patch MySQL2::execute